# The path admin/content/files is missing in Drupal 8.5

Tags: views, 8, files

I have installed Drupal 8.5 and today I realised that the tab `admin/content/files` is missing. Thanks to my backups I realized that this tab link is already missing since the 14th of March. Prior to the disappearance on the link I did not install any module. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: we will need more information before we can help you solve this ... but you can setup both in different location and probably compare them.  See if they have different enabled modules `drush pm-list --type=module --status=enabled`.  Are there any file related modules that might interfere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mistake I’ve disabled the View that generates the page, and the only thing I needed was to enable it again, and the tab reappeared. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Maybe was the same problem for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was because the route that creates the page (view.files.page_1) was not recognized by Drupal. Why? I don't know, but I reinstalled the Views UI and the Views module and the problem was solved.

You can read about this problem in [Add Item for Files under Content Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar/issues/2952643#comment-12535112) and this is why we added in the [Admin Toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar) module a [validation](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-03-20/admin_toolbar-add_files_menu_link-2952643-20-d8.patch) for the route. The file module can be installed and the route can be missed from the site.